# Is there a way to receive constructor arguments for PDO setFetchMode as associative array?

Tags: php, pdo

In this case:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'ClassName', $pdoargs);
```

When I pass `$pdoargs` as an associative array, I get it in the class constructor, but not as an associative array anymore but as a numeric array.

Is there a way to receive the array as associative?

Comment: As far as im aware, php will pass each item as a seperate parameter - if you want a single parameter which is an array, nest it in an outer array, eg `$ctorargs = [['name'=>'jon'...]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can get your question, it is not directly related to PDO, but to  function arguments in general.

So, if you want an associative array to be sent into constructor, you can make it this way

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'ClassName', array($pdoargs));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot _Your Common Sense_, afeter a lot of investigation, your  recommendation is the only suitable, it seems theres no way to get the array as associative, no parameter, nada.